# Pausing the throttle on exchange server 2013

Tags: exchange-server-2013

We need to pause the throttling of our exchange server 2013 for 90 days until we upgrade the server and exchange due to this error in the logs:

Connecting Exchange server version is out-of-date; connection to Exchange Online blocked for 20 mins/hr. For more information see https://aka.ms/ExchangeBuildCompliance.

It's running on Server 2012 R2. If i try and run below in Powershell it's showing as invalid i.e. not recognized.

`New-TenantExemptionInfo -BlockingScenario UnpatchedOnPremServer -NumberOfDays 90`

I cannot complete via this article - https://aka.ms/ExchangeBuildCompliance , as it's on prem back to a larger company Exchange Online, so the GUI report shows nothing.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

`New-TenantExemptionInfo -BlockingScenario UnpatchedOnPremServer -NumberOfDays 90` command shows not recognized. Using powershell 5.1, exchange 2013 and Server 2012 R2